# Can my .NET applications run on Mac and Linux if people have Mono installed?

Tags: .net, mono, windows

I'd like to develop C# applications in Mono, and I was wondering:

Can these also be run on Mac and Linux if the users have Mono installed?

Comment: So long as you aren't doing anything OS specific. Testing is the only way to known for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your application is compiled with the Mono toolchain rather than the Microsoft one, it will run on any OS that is supported by Mono.

Note that for compatibility with Mono you can't use some .NET APIs. AFAIK WinForms and WPF is in no usable state - for desktop applications use GTK# instead.

Comment: Would you say it's worth it to buy a book on C# and .NET if I'm going to be developing applications with Mono?

Comment: Yes, certainly. The C# language is the same, as well as the core parts of the Base Class Library.

Comment: @chris It doesn't need to be compiled with the mono toolchain at all, that's the whole point.

Comment: @Thibaudau: That's only half the truth. Using the Mono toolchain ensures that your assemblies are really fully compatible with the Mono runtime.

Comment: Testing does that too as well as using the mono utilities that help test this. Cross compiling sounds like a lot of additional work, the whole point of mono is to be an alternate runtime that is binary compatible, so you don't "need" to compile with it. You sure can, but you definately don't need, and the post wasn't stating that

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, some applications will work as is (copy paste the exe from Windows to linux or mac and it just works). Some other won't at all.

You need to make sure you don't use anything that's not supported by mono, like the WPF APIs for example or other Microsoft specific APIs. Also you don't want to to any native interop as the native APIs won't be the same in most cases.

So it depends, if we're talking console application or winform application and you make sure to test on both and make sure to only use the subset they both support, then yes it will just run as is without changes.